# .js file won't work when opened directly, works perfectly when opened through terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, cmd, syntax-error

I created a simple JavaScript code that makes use of [an unofficial Google Trends API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-trends-api#api-methods) for a hobbyist data analysis project. The VS Code editor gives no error, and when I use built in cmd terminal of vs code to load it with
`node index` but on opening it through windows explorer, I recieve :

Syntax Error

Code 800A03EA

Line 1, Char 1

.

I know that the node modules are successfully installed, because the code works when executed from terminal, so what might cause this result?

Is there something to do with the script blocker? If yes, how to disable it? This is my first code ever so I know close to nothing, please explain in simple terms. :D

Comment: try describe you question better to try understand the situation. Use code examples or something that can describe the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can help. Open cmd as administrator and run:
`regsvr32 jscript.dll` 
`regsvr32 vbscript.dll`

Edit: you may have to restart your PC

Comment: This did not work for the main file, but the test for the main file now runs well when executed through explorer. I think there must be some underlying issue with the API I'm using, as now I can run any .js file that does not depend on the API module. This resolved the part it had to! Thank you